# The ultimate book on mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request

hope I'm asking in the right forum, if not let me know and I'll delete the question :)

I'm looking for a book on logic that contains more than just first order logic and propositional calculus.
I'd like to learn about stuff like LTL, CTL, and so on. Is there something like a "Logic bible" or a standart reference?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Do you mean LTL/CTL in the sense of temporal logics, or something else?

Comment: yes! computational tree logic, and linear temporal logic...basiclly logic beside the standart logic teached in the first two semesters of computer sience or math :D

Comment: Once you leave the realm of first-order logic things really start branching depending on your interests. For example, if you're interested in strengthenings of first-order logic for studying the same sorts of structures - like second-order logic, infinitary logic, generalized quantifier logics, etc. - you land in classical abstract model theory and the massive volume [Model-theoretic logics](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235417263) is a great resource. (cont'd)

Comment: If you're interested in modal and intuitionistic  logics, [Chagrov/Zakharyaschev](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modal-logic-9780198537793?cc=us&lang=en&) is excellent - but if I recall correctly it doesn't say much about temporal logics. There is also a class of things called spatial logics, which have [their own handbook](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781402055867). And so on. I think beyond FOL the subject is just too broad to have a genuine "book of all."

Comment: See [**A Companion to Philosophical Logic**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1405145757) edited by Dale Jacquette (2002) and the 18-volume (current number) [**Handbook of Philosophical Logic**](https://www.springer.com/series/6024?detailsPage=titles) edited by  Gabbay/Guenthner (1983-present) and [**Handbook of Mathematical Logic**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0444863885) edited by Jon Barwise (1977).

Comment: I think this is a fine MSE question, and I'm not sure the downvoter/closevoter(s) understand how hard it is to find advanced logic resources; most easy-to-find texts are either elementary or *extremely* narrow-focused.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just checked some of the links and "Model Theory Logics" sounds great! And yes, I already spend some hours googling for it :D So thank you a lot sir!

Comment: It should be mentioned that [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) (research of semantic consequence) and [proof theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory) (research of syntactic consequence) are both major branches of mathematical logic. If you focus only on model theory, you miss proof theory entirely. But both fields are also too vast be be compressed into a single book (that is not ridiculously large).