# Best book that covers all / most topics in logic

Tags: book-recommendation

I am looking for a textbook or a series of textbooks that covers all or most of the topics in logic, that includes Aristotelian term logic, Stoic logic, Islamic logic, medieval logic, predicate calculus, all or most of non-classical logics, algebraic logic, model theory, proof theory, universal algebra, etc. In short, something that covers all historical and contemporary areas of logic in a most comprehensive way.

Comment: "something that covers all historical and contemporary areas of logic in a most comprehensive way" That simply doesn't exist - logic is a big subject.

Comment: What would be the closest thing to that in your opinion?

Comment: I really don't think there's anything that comes close, but - per my answer - you might look at the "Handbook(s) of the history of logic" series. It's >6000 pages in total, though ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You set, to put it mildly, a rather high bar:

> includes Aristotelian term logic, Stoic logic, Islamic logic, medieval logic, predicate calculus, all or most of non-classical logics, algebraic logic, model theory, proof theory, universal algebra, etc.

This is simply far too much material to be contained in a single book, or even a small set of books. The closest thing I can think of is the [Handbook of the history of logic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/handbook/handbook-of-the-history-of-logic/volumes) ... a series comprising **eleven volumes**, each with more than $600$ pages. And even then, many important topics are omitted. Meanwhile, even the "simple" topic of nonclassical propositional logics can lend itself to a [~$1500$-page treatment](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwisoN68pcftAhXTZs0KHdWYC3EQFjAEegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fjournals.uvic.ca%2Findex.php%2Fpir%2Farticle%2Fview%2F12610%2F3800&usg=AOvVaw1Ew7NZ0r_1jyWBmNMvJnAo).

Comment: This is also discussed in the comments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925152/28111).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one can do much better than the 100+ page literature guide on introductory logic texts on [logicmatters.net](https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/). The target audience here is not exclusively mathematicians, but also philosophy majors, so you'll not just be limited to the first- and second- order variants of mostly classical predicate logical logic that math faculties have by and large settled at 100 years ago.

In closing - while I know of topics such as Indian [Jaina seven-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaina_seven-valued_logic) - in view of the scope you want to cover in your question, I'm not sure if you will find a text that deeply discusses Stoic and Islamic logic on the one hand, and on the same time formal model theory.